# Googleドライブからファイルをダウンロードし、ダウンロードが完了したらファイルを実行するには

Tags: python, google-drive-sdk

Pythonで、[google_drive_downloader](https://pypi.org/project/googledrivedownloader/)を使用して、Googleドライブからファイルをダウンロードし、ダウンロードが完了したことを検知した後にファイルを実行したいです。

[以下の方法](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ja/python/python%EF%BC%9Aurl%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6google%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/827287384/)で、Googleドライブからダウンロードすることは出来ましたが、ダウンロードが完了したことを検知することが難しいです。どうしたら良いですか？

```
from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader as gdd

gdd.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id='1iytA1n2z4go3uVCwE__vIKouTKyIDjEq',
                                    dest_path='C:/Users/test/Desktop/setup.exe')
```

ダウンロード完了後は、subprocess.Popen()で開こうと思っています。

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(exeFilePath)
```

Comment: 直接問題を解決する内容でなく申し訳ありません。[スクリプト](https://github.com/ndrplz/google-drive-downloader/blob/be1aba9e2e43b2375475f19d8214ca50a8621bd6/google_drive_downloader/google_drive_downloader.py#L20)を見るとReturnsがNoneになっていますので、この場合、ダウンロードが完了したかどうかは目的のファイルがローカル側でファイルとして作成されたかどうか、あるいは`print('Done.')`があるようですので、ここで判断するしかないのかもしれません。あるいは、公式の[googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)であればダウンロードが完了した際にスクリプトを実行することは可能です。これについてのサンプルはいくつか[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgoogle-drive-api%5d%20download%20python)でご確認いただけるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます！